# Wikidata Dumps - Long QIDs

Tags: ontology, wikidata, wikimedia-dumps

While playing with the dump, I came across many entries like the following:

http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q12258SCD97A47E-A0CA-453F-B01A-DEE8829139BF
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P646v "/m/021821" .

- what does the `Q12258SCD97A47E-A0CA-453F-B01A-DEE8829139BF` stand for? it seems to be a QID followed by something else.
- What does the property: P646v stands for, it doesn't seem to be valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Wikidata [item](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Items) has [statements](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Statements), and each statement consists of a [statement property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Properties) and one or more [statement values](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Statements#Values). Each statement value has a [value](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Glossary#Values) and additional [qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Qualifiers) (property plus value) and [references](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Sources) (group of one or more properties and values).

One statement property-value pair form a [claim](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Glossary#Claims_and_statements). Each claim has unique identifier which is formed from the item id, `$` (S) and an [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (*"32 hexadecimal digits displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters"*).

So, in your case the item [Q12258](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q12258) has property [P646](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P646) with value `/m/021821` and form a claim with unique identifier with UUID: [CD97A47E-A0CA-453F-B01A-DEE8829139BF](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&format=xml&claim=Q12258$CD97A47E-A0CA-453F-B01A-DEE8829139BF).

```
<property id="P646">
    <claim type="statement" id="Q12258$CD97A47E-A0CA-453F-B01A-DEE8829139BF"></claim>
</property>
```

If the item has property P646 with more than one value, unique id for each one of the values will be formed.

Properties in Wikidata do not directly correspond to properties in RDF. P646v is **RDF property** where postfix **v** means that this property is used for link to the **value**. Postfix **s** is used for link to the **statement**, and for **qualifiers** and **references** is used **q** and **r** respectively.

An [example](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&format=xml&claim=q42$b88670f8-456b-3ecb-cf3d-2bca2cf7371e) with Q42 for P26 which has one value, two qualifiers (P580 and P582) and reference:

[image: graph]

For simpler RDF exports there is still one RDF property with postfix **c**. You can find more information in [Introducing Wikidata to the Linked Data Web](http://korrekt.org/papers/Wikidata-RDF-export-2014.pdf) (p.6, Ch.3. Representing Wikidata Content in RDF).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the property P646v is correct?  [P646](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P646) is the property for Freebase identifiers which matches the format of the data value.

As was answered on the Wikidata mailing list, although the subject URI contains the entity QID, that information shouldn't be relied upon and you should instead follow the edges of the graph.  Presumably someplace else in the graph there's a triple that says:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q12258  http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q12258SCD97A47E-A0CA-453F-B01A-DEE8829139BF

Comment: I pasted one of the entries from the Wikidata nt dump. 
There are also entries with Properties like: `P646-freebase`.

i.e:

 <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21597748> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P646-freebase> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0g3v35> .

Comment: Im not so sure, in prev dump versions I was able to create a mapping to MIDs just grepping `P646`.
In the latest dump I cant find P646 alone, I find lots of P646s , P646v and P646-freebase.

I'm a bit confused.