# What is a "c" property suffix in a Wikidata SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata

Reading the paper "[Wikidata through the Eyes of DBpedia](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.04180.pdf)" (2015), I came across this SPARQL query:

```
select * WHERE {
  ?place wkdt:P31c/wkdt:P279c* wkdt:Q2221906;
  wkdt:P17c wkdt:Q183. }
```

I don't understand what the **c** means beside the property codes.

The authors explain (page 8, lines 1 and 2) that "*querying for reified
statement in Wikidata needs to properly suffix the Wikidata property with c/s/q*"

This is the first time I hear about these suffixes and my research on the net does not help.

Could someone tell me more about that ?

Comment: I think this is old dump format: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34680429/7879193. Possibly this format is described somewhere in [history](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format&action=history).  Perhaps `wkdt:P31c`, `wkdt:P31s`, `wkdt:P31q` are just syntactical variants of modern `wdt:P31`, `ps:P31`, `pq:P31` respectively.

Comment: Thank you, @Stanislav ! The word to look for was "postfix" and not "suffix". I will dig into the history. Tanks again.

Comment: And possibly this is a Wikidata Toolkit specific dump format: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download#RDF_dumps

Comment: BTW: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T90121